# Printing vector-labels on vector layers by geoserver print module (MapFish)

Tags: javascript, pdf, openlayers, geoserver

I am using some vector layers on openlayers(2.14) with geoserver(2.2.3) and Mapfish print module.

The thing is that I get a style on my point vector layer and also have label on it. All it's ok in the map, both things appears with no problem, but when i generate the pdf with the mapfish module, something strange happens...  In the final pdf, vectors dissapear and only labels are printed, i guess the problem is the combination of them, because if I quit the labels on the map, the vector points are shown in tne pdf.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance...